# How can I loop and generate counts of matching nodes in XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I need to loop through XML data and generate a document that will say how many times text appears in a node. I'm close but I can't get it to work. I'm using xsl 1.0 and can't update it.

```
<xsl:variable name="found">
 <root>
    <content name="test">A</content>
    <content name="test">A</content>
    <content name="test">A</content>
    <content name="test">B</content>
    <content name="test">B</content>
    <content name="test">C</content>
  </root>
</xsl:variable>


<xsl:template match="document">
  <document>
    <xsl:for-each select="exsl:node-set($found)//content[@name='test']">
      <content name="found-count">
        <xsl:value-of select="." />,<xsl:value-of
          select="count(exsl:node-set($found)//content[.= text()])"
        />
      </content>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </document>
</xsl:template>
```

The output is...

```
<document>
  <content name="found-count">A,6</content>
  <content name="found-count">A,6</content>
  <content name="found-count">A,6</content>
  <content name="found-count">B,6</content>
  <content name="found-count">B,6</content>
  <content name="found-count">C,6</content>
</document>
```

I need it to be this(I will de-dupe later):

```
<document>
  <content name="found-count">A,3</content>
  <content name="found-count">A,3</content>
  <content name="found-count">A,3</content>
  <content name="found-count">B,2</content>
  <content name="found-count">B,2</content>
  <content name="found-count">C,1</content>
</document>
```

I think the issue is in my statment

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(exsl:node-set($found)//content[.= text()])" />
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this...

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(exsl:node-set($found)//content[.= text()])"
```

With this...

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(exsl:node-set($found)//content[.= current()/text()])"
```

The `current()` node is the `content` selected by the parent `xsl:for-each`. Without specifying `current()` then doing `content[.= text()])` is the same as doing `content[.= ./text()])` (i.e. it is referring to the context node), so you are getting content whose text is equal to itself.

Alternatively, use an `xsl:key` here, and do this....

```
<xsl:key name="content" match="content[@name='test']" use="." />

<xsl:template match="document">
  <document>
    <xsl:for-each select="exsl:node-set($found)">
      <xsl:for-each select=".//content[@name='test']">
        <content name="found-count">
          <xsl:value-of select="." />,<xsl:value-of select="count(key('content', text()))" />
        </content>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </document>
</xsl:template>
```

This way, you can then use [Muenchian Grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html) to de-duplicate...

```
<xsl:template match="document">
  <document>
    <xsl:for-each select="exsl:node-set($found)">
      <xsl:for-each select=".//content[@name='test'][generate-id() = generate-id(key('content', text())[1])]">
        <content name="found-count">
          <xsl:value-of select="." />,<xsl:value-of select="count(key('content', text()))" />
        </content>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </document>
</xsl:template>
```